# avplayer not playing audio in video which is captured through device camera in IOS objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avfoundation, avplayer

I am capturing the video from the device camera and than storing that video into the device local memory and than in the next screen I am playing that video using **AVPlayer** but I am not getting sound from video.Here is code of video playback

```
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];

    _avPlayer=[[AVPlayer alloc]initWithURL:url]; //URL of my recorded video
    _avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_avPlayer];
    [_avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.videoview.frame.size.width, self.videoview.frame.size.height)];
    [_avPlayerLayer setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor]CGColor]];
    _avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    [self.pictureview.layer addSublayer:_avPlayerLayer];
    [_avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    _avPlayer = [self rotateVideoPlayer:_avPlayer withDegrees:0.0];
    _avPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    [_avPlayer play];
```

**Note:-** Video has sound because After preview, I am uploading the video on server and in that I can hear a sound from recorded video.

I am using **AVCaptureSession** to record video and has **added** **AVMediaTypeVideo**  and **AVMediaTypeAudio** **as AVCaptureDevice.** So will it make any problem at a time of playback. Before Playback I am removing AVCaptureDevice devices from the AVCaptureSession and than playing the captured video.

Comment: So the problem is that the video isn't being captured, or not played back ?

Comment: Problem is that it is not playing audio in video in playback.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue a time ago, and adding this code to AppDelegate method helped me:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
        NSError *err;
        AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
        bool success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                                      error:&err];
        if (!success) {
            DLog(@"error changing audio mode %@", err);
            [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback
                           error:&err];
            if (err) {
                DLog(@"error changing audio mode %@", err);
            }
        }
}
```

Also if it doesn't help, try to turn off the "mute" button on your device.
Also check error description if it does exist.

**UPDATE:**
Do you initialize your audio input something like this?

```
        AVCaptureDevice *audioDevice = [[AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] firstObject];
        AVCaptureDeviceInput *audioDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:audioDevice error:&error];

        if (error)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error);
        }

        if ([session canAddInput:audioDeviceInput])
        {
            [session addInput:audioDeviceInput];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it only work only 2 times after that I am getting same problem of no sound.

Comment: Try to store the video to camera roll, and then try to play it from native ios app, the sound will exist?

Comment: In that sound is exist but when I am trying to play preview in my app than it is not playing sound.

Comment: I am using AVCaptureSession to record video and has added AVMediaTypeVideo  and AVMediaTypeAudio as AVCaptureDevice. So will it make any problem at a time of playback. Before Playback I am removing AVCaptureDevice devices from the AVCaptureSession and than playing the captured video.

Comment: what about AVCaptureMovieFileOutput? How do you initialize it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112165/discussion-between-eugene-zaychenko-and-darshit-vadodaria).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily play video with `MPMoviePlayerController`. In one my project I am playing like,

```
self.videoController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];

[self.videoController setContentURL:videourl];
[self.videoController.view setFrame:CGRectMake (0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[self.view addSubview:self.videoController.view];

UIButton *closeButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width-60, 20, 60, 30)];

[closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(cancel:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[closeButton setTitle:@"Cancel" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[self.videoController.view addSubview:closeButton];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(videoPlayBackDidFinish:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:self.videoController];

[self.videoController play];
```

I am adding close button and observer, you not need to do that if not required.

And don't forget to import `<MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>`

**Update :**

```
 audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];


    NSError *err;
    NSError *error;


    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &err];

    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR occured %@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }

    [audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];

    [audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
    // [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];
    [audioSession overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideSpeaker
                                    error:nil];

    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];



    audioPlayer = nil;
    //NSError *error;


    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]
                   initWithContentsOfURL:self.audioRecorder1.url
                   error:&error];
    // audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
    audioPlayer.delegate = self;
    [audioPlayer prepareToPlay];
      [audioPlayer play];
```

You use avplayer instead of audio player! main concern is session!

Hope this will help:)

Comment: I have also used your code but still not getting sound of recorded video

Comment: How you recording video?

Comment: I am using AVCaptureSession to record video and has added AVMediaTypeVideo  and AVMediaTypeAudio as AVCaptureDevice. So will it make any problem at a time of playback. Before Playback I am removing AVCaptureDevice devices from the AVCaptureSession and than playing the captured video.

Comment: I think you are not getting audio when recording! Why you are not using `imagepickercontroller` to record video?

Comment: I am getting audio in recording because after preview I am uploading that video to our server. When I am playing that video on server it has an audio.

Comment: Strange problem then!!

Comment: Can you suggest any other thing which I should try?

Comment: have you test on different device?

Comment: Yes I have test this on multiple devices but facing the same issue.

Comment: Try my update in answer. I am using this in my one project for recording and playing. if it can help

Comment: Check that you haven't another shared session with different configuration. you should nil it after use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112169/discussion-between-darshit-vadodaria-and-lion).